# Only half of the 16x2 LCD appears

Tags: lcd

I searched for answers but I didn't found any answers to my problem. Actually, I use my Arduino with a 16x2 LCD screen. But as the title says, only the half of the screen displays (8x2), the other side just doesn't turn on. Do someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: In order to get good help in solving your problem, please provide more details on your specific situation. Include your wiring diagram (schematic, or something similar) and the code you are using, and as much information as you know about the LCD panel you have (datasheet, source, etc.)

Comment: Try configuring it as 8x4 I found many strange configurations when I bought cheap LCDs from China.

Comment: i've never seen/heard of that particular problem/failure mode, so it might be defective.